# FreesWitch speech recognition speechtools.jm Error

Tags: javascript, xml, v8, freeswitch, spidermonkey

i am trying to use freesWitch but headed with this error . can sombody help how i can resolve this ?  i do get the xml but it can't parse it accordingly

```
<result grammar="pizza_order">
  <interpretation grammar="pizza_order" confidence="100">
    <input mode="speech">delivery</input>
  </interpretation>
</result>
```

the point where i am stuck is , i need to parse xml each attribute and each node but i am unable to use dom parser aswel, the only reference i got was

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/JavaScript+example+-+XML#JavaScriptexample-XML-Examples

but i almost tried everything but cannot get the data out of that XML , kindly help me to get parse this small XML successfully or any simple logic which doesn't use any parser in javascript will also work ,  i have this xml in string aswel. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var input1 = xml.getChild('interpretation');

var input2 = input1.getChild('input');
console_log('info', 'XML newChild attrbute firstattr: ' + input1.getAttribute('grammar'));



                                                var score = input1.getAttribute('confidence');
                                                var child = xml.getChild('result');



                                                var ahsan = xml.serialize();
                                                console_log('info', 'Full XML ::\n' + ahsan +  " method=" + input2.data  );
                                                console_log("debug", "----XML---> :\n" + body + "\n");


                                                console_log("debug", "----Hit score [" + score + "]/" +
                                                grammar_object.min_score + "/" + grammar_object.confirm_score + "\n");
```

I think it will solve your problem

Comment: Great @Asad ur Rehman u are a life saver ,... i was stuck from 2 days . thanx for the help.

Comment: Im trying to migrate the https://freeswitch.org/fisheye/browse/~raw,r=70f4d93c3c7066fdbef0b93b968a24c907e3ab3a/freeswitch/scripts/js_modules/SpeechTools.jm to XML but not working can you shed some light? No error is thrown https://freeswitch.org/jira/browse/FS-9935